# How to reply properly to 'Thank you'

Tags: conversation, greetings

Consider following situation

> You are a polite person and you hold a door open for someone that comes immediately after you. He/she says: "Thank You!"

What is the correct expression to reply to him/her? I was thinking of *Here you are* but I am not sure.

Comment: "**You are (very) welcome**" and "**My pleasure**" are formal, and  "**No problem**" is informal. "Here you are" would be something you'd say as you held the door, before he went through.

Comment: Define "*properly*".

Comment: @Drew By *properly* I meant *in an appropriate fashion* (correct English expression in the right register).

Comment: Define "*an appropriate fashion*". the point is that this question is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Drew I understand that you consider this question to be opinion-based. However, my goal was to find the correct English expression in the right register, something that may not be straightforward for non-native speakers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just say: You're welcome. / You're very welcome. / No problem.

Comment: Or just a bright smile.

Answer (score 1):

"De nada" or, adding to an Australian trend, "no worries".

This is because the most polite answer to any expressions of gratitude is to point out that no gratitude is needed.

Answer (score 0):

"No problem' with a smile! that would be good!

Comment: Please explain why this is a suitable ways to reply to "Thank you", given the above context.